# Detect input is character or number

Tags: c, optimization, input

I am writing a program to calculate sum of 2 variables. One of these is a number from 1 to 10, and the other is one letter of the alphabet (uppercase) which has value corresponding to its order. The input can be only number, only letter or both.

For instance:

**Input**

```
10  7     
C  8
E  D
9  F
```

**Output**

```
17
11
9
15
```

This is my code (This question suppose to be posted on codereview, but for some reason I can't format code right way on codereview. Please forgive me).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){     
    char a[3], b[3];                        
    int m,n;
    //these variables hold the value of grade after converted  
                
    scanf("%s%s", a, b);

    if (a[1]!='\0')         
    {
      //this is because only number 10 has 2 digits    
        m=10;
    }
    else if (a[0]>=49 && a[0]<=57)
    {
        m=a[0]-48;      //in ascii table, 49 stands of 1 and 57 stands for 9
    }
    else
    {
        m=a[0]-64;      //in ascii table, 65 stands for 'A'
    }

    if (b[1]!='\0')              
    {
        n=10;
    }
    else if (b[0]>=49 && b[0]<=57)      
    {
        n=b[0]-48;
    }
    else         
    {
        n=b[0]-64;
    }

    printf("%d", m+n);
    return 0;
}
```

It works but I think it is a little bit complicated. So I want to ask if there is any way to optimize the detection.

And how to deal with large input number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please copy-paste (as text!) your [mre] into the question itself. Questions needs to be self-contained, and main parts of it should be on sites where contents can change or disappear anytime.

Comment: As for your problem, [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) might help.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, it is really helpful to me

Comment: Before posting your next question, please learn how to format your code properly in a question (I've done it for you). It's easy and it will take you only a few minutes to learn it.

Comment: I really appreciate that. Thanks for editing my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stroll` function to convert string to `long long`. It looks much cleaner, and this program can deal from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807` as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  char string_num1[20], string_num2[20];
  scanf("%s%s", string_num1, string_num2);
  long long num1 = strtoll(string_num1, NULL, 10);
  long long num2 = strtoll(string_num2, NULL, 10);
  long long num3 = num1 + num2;

  printf("%lld", num3);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s%s", string_num1, string_num2);` is two buffer overflows waiting to happen.  Better to use `fgets()` - or even better `getline()` if available - and then you can directly use `strtoll()` on the returned line of input without ever falling into the `*scanf()` morass.

Comment: Is it ok if I only use 1 '%s' in 'scanf' like 'scanf("%s", string_num1);' then 'scanf("%s", string_num2);' in next line?